# "Misplaced allignment tab character" line 53

Tags: miktex

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\topmargin=0pt
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=8.5in
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\large\bf\LaTeX\ Example 7}
\end{center}
This example demostrates two methods for typesetting piecewise defined functions.
The array structure can be used to typeset function definitions that have multiple cases:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{r@{\quad\mathrm{if}\quad} r}
%%
%%% Using r instead of i was the only way i could get the file to compile
%%
x^2-1 & x\in (-\infty,-1]\vspace{2pt}\\
{\displaystyle \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}}&x\in(-1,1)
\vspace{6pt}\\
x^2+1 & x\in[1, \infty) \vspace{4pt}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{equation}
   f(x)=\left\{
     \begin{array}{r@{\quad\mathrm{if}\quad} i}
       x^2-1 & x\in (-\infty,-1]\vspace{2pt}\\
      {\displaystyle \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}}&x\in(-1,1)
          \vspace{6pt}\\
      x^2+1 & x\in[1,\infty) \vspace{4pt}
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
Observations:
\begin{itemize}
\item The function definition is an array structure with two columns, the first one right justi-
fied, and the second one left justified \verb+(+because of the \verb+{+r\verb+@{\+quad\verb+\+textrm\verb+{+if\verb+}\+quad\verb+}+1\verb+})+.
\item The \verb+@{\+quad\verb+\+textrm\verb+{+if\verb+}\+quad\verb+}+ is called and \verb+@-+expression.  It causes the word ''if'' \verb+(+in roman font\verb+)+ to be inserted between the first and second columns.  The \verb+\+quad causes one space proportional to the current font size to be inserted.
\item The \verb+\+displaystyle increases the font size in the fraction of the second line of the
definition.  Without it, the expression in the second line appears disproportionately small.
\item The two \verb+\+vspaces insert some vertical spaces between the alternative cases of the 
function definition.
\item Note that \verb+\+left\verb+\{+ is balanced with \verb+\+right . .
\end{itemize}
Here is another way to typeset the definition of f:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
  x^2-1                                                 & \text{if $x\ in(-\infty,-1]$}\\
{\displaystyle \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}} &\text{if $x\in(-1,1)$}\\
x^2+1                                                  &\text{if $x\in[1, \infty)$}
\end{cases}
\text{\ \ \ .}
\end {equation}
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2-1                                                   &\text{if $x\in(-\infty,-1]$}\\
{\displaystyle \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}} &\text{if $x\in(-1,1)$}\\
x^2+1                                                  &\text{if $x\in[1, \infty)$}
\end{cases}
\text{\ \ \ .}
\end {equation}
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: didn't you just ask this earlier, you can not use `i`

Comment: Please note that you can _edit_ questions. Is this supposed to have a follow up comment to the previous question? As it stands it just has an example and no question at all.

Comment: Im sorry I uploaded the wrong file I will upload the right one

Comment: Btw, ive tried replacing i with 1, r, and c and it still wont compile.